# android:copy sqlite database to device manually

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have developed an android app which will run just on one device,and i have an SQLite DB and i want to copy that in //data/data//databases directory on device internal storage,but i have two problems:

1. This directory for my app is not visible for me, while files of some other apps are visible.
2. I created this directory manually and copied the DB there, but it didn't work.

In emulator i copied db to the files that was created automatically and app works properly.
thanks for your helps

and this is my sqlite code:

```
 SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("a",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM person WHERE id=?", new String [] {String.valueOf(1)});
    c.moveToFirst();
    String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));      
    db.close();
    TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy your SQLite database in `assets` folder, which is inside the main project folder. You cannot place it directly inside the `/data/data/your application package/`.

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) to get going on this.

There is a line in code,

`private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/";`

replace this with

`private static String DB_PATH;`

and

update the constructor to

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    // you will get a warning if you'll try to hardcode your path
    DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
}
```

rest is all explained in this tutorial.

Comment: why cant he copy directly to _/data/data/your application package/_ ?

Comment: Because you should never make assumptions about the filesystem or the directory structure. `Context` provides a `getDatabasePath` method for exactly this reason.

Comment: Lets suppose it works well by copying the DB to specific directory, but what will you do if you have to upload your app to android market ? How will you copy it to user's device ?

Comment: thanks,i tried this link and it works on emulator but not on device.i haven't data/data/ on my device,generally files related to apps stores in android/data/package name,but files related to apps which i developed aren't there!!!